# How do I merge these two objects in Inkscape such that the space in between is gone?

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I'd like to remove the white space in the screenshot I took of an Inkscape file and merge the two pink objects together into a single object.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

To make a united object we may select *Path > Union* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> after we had selected the objects we wanted to unite.

Gaps between objects will remain visible in the united objects. Therefore we  have to remove any gaps before we proceed.

This can be done in several ways, depending on the precision we need for the objects or their surroundings:

1. Move objects until they **overlap**
   *By this the original position of the object will change of course*
2. Move **object handles** until they **snap** to the neighboring object's handle

   - in path mode [image]enable snapping [image]to handles    [image]or corners.
   - Drag neighboring handles until they "snap":

   [image]

   - Make a union object <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>.
3. Create a third **object filling the gap** (this object can be larger than the gap):

   - It is easier to create such an object when snapping is enabled.

   [image]

   - Select all three objects to create a unified object <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open *Object > Align and Distribute…* tab.
2. Select the upper shape, then the lower shape (with *Shift* key stroked so that both are selected).
3. Set *"Relative to"* to *"Last selected"* in the *"Align and Distribute…*" tab.
4. Finally, click on [image: "align bottom edge of objects to the top of the anchor"] ("align bottom edge of objects to the top of the anchor").

In this example the lower shape will be the anchor (and therefore won't move), bus obviously you can play with mentioned parameters and/or the button [image: "align top edge of objects to the bottom of the anchor"] ("align top edge of objects to the bottom of the anchor") if you want it otherwise.